# Set default value for SCSS variables

Tags: sass

I want to do something like this :

```
    $color: var(--color) | #000;
```

I tried to use `!default` but did not managed to make it work, I used it like this :

var.scss

```
$color: #000 !default;
```

main.scss

```
@use 'var' with (
   $color: red;
)
```

To clarify, `var.scss` and `main.scss` are in the same directory.

My main goal with that is to set default value and if the user want to modify these values he can with `@use ... with()`

Answer (score 0):

In Sass you would write (no `;` at all)

```
@use 'var' with ($color: red)
```

in SCSS you would write (`;` at the very end, not after `red`)

```
@use 'var' with (
  $color: red
);
```

also note: Only Dart Sass currently supports `@use`. Users of other implementations must use the `@import` rule instead.

Comment: Unfortunetly it still doesn't work with your proposed solution

Comment: have you tried using the HEX code instead of `red`?

Comment: I've just tried and did not changed a thing :/

Comment: oh and what kind of Sass are you using? `@ use` is only supported by Dart Sass "Only Dart Sass currently supports @use. Users of other implementations must use the `@ import` rule instead."

Comment: To be faire I don't really know, I just did an `npm i sass`. But if it is only supported by Dart sass is it the best option to use it then ? Is there another 'pure sass' version ?

Comment: There is Dart Sass, Lib Sass, Node Sass and Ruby Sass. You should find the type of sass in the package.json.

Comment: In my dependencies there is `"sass": "^1.68.0"`, no more no less

Comment: Dart Sass may be the best option already. Dart Sass would support the `@ use`. Have a look at the documentation to get more insights on the differences: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

Comment: I think you're using Dart Sass. v1.68.0 is the latest version of it. So that should be fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255462/discussion-between-jessman5-and-eli-ott).

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I have found a workaround that does not require the end user to use SCSS to modify the values.

Now what I do is that I set the variables in pure SCSS.

And when putting the style on an element I use the CSS `var()` fallback like that :

```
color: var(--color, $color);
```

And that works perfectly fine because when the pure CSS variable isn't set my SCSS variables will take its place.

And the user can still modify it by changing the root variables like that :

```
:root {
   --color: red;
}
```

Little downside is that I have to write two times the same variable names in the css which is quite dirty, but it does the job